# How to model with EntityFramework extensible fields for the entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following requirement, on my app the Entities will come with some fields, however the user needs to be able to add additional fields to the entity and then values for those fields.

I was thinking something like this but I am not sure if it would be a good approach or not.

The base class is an entity (Not sure which fields I need to add here)

```
public class Entidad
{
}
```

Then the Company Class will inherit from Entity

```
public class Empresa : Entidad
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string NIT { get; set; }
    public string NombreRepresentanteLegal { get; set; }
    public string TelefonoRepresentanteLegal { get; set; }
    public string NombreContacto { get; set; }
    public string TelefonoContacto { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CampoAdicional> CamposAdicionales { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is an ICollection of additional fields. that class would have the fieldname, type and id

```
public class CampoAdicional
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NombreCampo { get; set; }
    public Tiposcampo TipoCampo { get; set; }
}
```

and then the field value would be something like this:

```
public class ValorCampo
{
    public Entidad Entidad { get; set; }
    public CampoAdicional Campo { get; set; }
    public string ValorTexto { get;set ; }
    public int ValorNumerico { get; set; }
}
```

However I am not sure if this is the correct model classes for my scenario and whether it would create the tables correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF works with lazy load so at least there are several "virtual" missings.
In all properties that does not use primitive types and in collections.

Can you extend more than one entity with additional fields? If so you need that ValorCampo contains the entity (Entidad) but the entity should have the Id so you need to move the Id from Empresa to Entidad. Otherwise you need ValorCampo should refer to Empresa not to Entidad

Comment: great, what would you recommend me for the views? Scaffolding Empresa¡? or Entidad? or CamposAdicionales or build everything from scratch?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean for scaffolding empresa. If you need to extend every Entity probably you should move also the collection to Entidad. But if you need to extend every entity type (Empresa and other entity types not mentioned in the example) with different specific field CampoAddicional need to be related to Empresa. Tell me the final solution :)))

Comment: PS: In my cases the additional fields are not searchable so I insert everything in a CLOB field (Text in SQL Server) like XML or like couples field_name description